# Изба = хижина, лачуга, конура, халупа?

Tags: лексика

Можно ли всякую избу назвать также хижиной, лачугой, конурой и халупой (все эти слова имеют значение некрепкого, ветхого или слабо укрепленного жилища, чаще всего деревянной избушки)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова "изба" и "хижина" имеют нейтральное значение (небольшой домик). Но хижина маленькая, а изба может быть любого размера. "Избушка" и "хижина" — синоним.

А "халупа" и "лачуга" указывают на бедность такого жилища. Конурой дом можно назвать только в переносном смысле, потому что слово это обозначает собачью будку. Назвать так можно не все избы, а те, что отличаются теснотой, грязью и/или неблагоустроенностью.

Comment: Изба может быть и вполне себе большой, и даже на несколько семей. Ни в коем случае не синоним с хижиной.

Comment: Согласен. исправил.